# Why the PeekMessage always return TRUE?

Tags: winapi, peekmessage

```
        // Main message loop

        MSG msg;
        ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof( msg ) );
        while(msg.message!=WM_QUIT)
        {

            if(PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) )
            {
                TranslateMessage( &msg );
                DispatchMessage( &msg );
            }
            else
            {
                Render();
            }
        }
```

The "render" function hasn't been executing

Comment: `PeekMessage` will return FALSE only when there is WM_QUIT in message queue. Only that and nothing else. You have to move `Render` function somewhere else, which depends on what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Dialecticus No, it returns `FALSE` when the queue is empty.

Comment: Well, hard to guess what message you keep receiving from the question.  I'll put a buck on WM_PAINT, generated over and over again when you don't call Begin/EndPaint().

Comment: Ouch, that's no `GetMessage` there. Slow brain, quick fingers...

Comment: Debugging tip: Log the messages. See what messages keep coming in and prevent your Render from running. Then see why those messages keep being generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`PeekMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx) documentation says this regarding the return value:

> If a message is available, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If no messages are available, the return value is zero.

When the message queue is empty, it will indeed return zero, i.e. `FALSE`. The conclusion therefore is that the message queue is never empty. And the most likely explanation for that is that one of the messages you handle in `DispatchMessage` leads to that same message being posted to the queue.

Comment: It's pretty standard in a game loop.

Comment: oh, I'm so careless. The WndProc has a empty case.

Comment: case WM_PAINT:
break;       so always have a WM_PAINT in message queue